# Can't install Python 3.8.13 using pyenv and Homebrew

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, python

I'm a new Linux learner. When I try to install python via pyenv, this error appears:

OS: Ubuntu 22.04

```
kev@kev-Modern-15-A5M:~$ pyenv install 3.8.13
Downloading Python-3.8.13.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.13/Python-3.8.13.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.8.13...
WARNING: The Python bz2 extension was not compiled. Missing the bzip2 lib?
WARNING: The Python readline extension was not compiled. Missing the GNU readline lib?
ERROR: The Python ssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?

Please consult to the Wiki page to fix the problem.
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems


BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 22.04 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/python-build.20220629160539.201051
Results logged to /tmp/python-build.20220629160539.201051.log

Last 10 log lines:
     ./python -E -m ensurepip \
        $ensurepip --root=/ ; \
fi
Looking in links: /tmp/tmppnia5_0_
Processing /tmp/tmppnia5_0_/setuptools-56.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
Processing /tmp/tmppnia5_0_/pip-22.0.4-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: setuptools, pip
  WARNING: The scripts pip3 and pip3.8 are installed in '/home/kev/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed pip-22.0.4 setuptools-56.0.0
```

Comment: just a hint run your pyenv with verbose output for clarity `pyenv install 3.12 -v`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by Homebrew, just uninstall and reinstall packages manually without Homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 22 LTS

#### Missing Library Problem in Python Installation with Pyenv

Before the fix:

```
$> pyenv install 3.11.0
```

command result:

```
pyenv: /home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.11.0 already exists
continue with installation? (y/N) y
Downloading Python-3.11.0.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.0/Python-3.11.0.tar.xz


Installing Python-3.11.0...
WARNING: The Python bz2 extension was not compiled. Missing the bzip2 lib?
WARNING: The Python readline extension was not compiled. Missing the GNU readline lib?
WARNING: The Python lzma extension was not compiled. Missing the lzma lib?
```

#### TLDR;

Recipe to fix:

```bash
sudo apt-get install build-essential zlib1g-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev liblzma-dev
```

#### Result

After the fix:

```bash
$> pyenv install 3.11.0
```

Command result:

```
pyenv: /home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.11.0 already exists
continue with installation? (y/N) y
Downloading Python-3.11.0.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.0/Python-3.11.0.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.11.0...
Installed Python-3.11.0 to /home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.11.0
```